# ¿Existen diferencias sonoras entre la “b” y la “v” en España?

Tags: modismos, diferencias-regionales, españa

Algunos amigos de Puerto Rico me dicen que cuando estuvieron en Valencia (España), escucharon que mucha gente hablaba diferenciando la “b” y “v”. ¿Es verdad?. ¿Existe alguna region que hable diferenciando la “b” y la “v” en España¿ ¿o en otra parte?

Answer (score 1):

Aunque en la antigüedad si podíamos encontrar esta peculiaridad de la diferencia, la "b" representaba el fonema oclusivo sonoro bilabial, mientras que la "v" el sonido era labiodental. Según algunos estudiosos, como Alarcos Llorach, la distinción entre "b y v" se mantendría hasta el S. XV, aunque otros piensan que desapareció antes de esa fecha.

Actualmente no existen discrepancias entre la pronunciación de la "b y v" en el mundo hispánico. Así para nosotros suena igual decir, "vaca" que "baca". Sin embargo, el "valenciano", como una de las lenguas que se habla en España, si es capaz de distinguir entre la "b y v" y puede que por adstrato o mantenimiento, su influencia se extienda más allá en algunas personas o en algunas comarcas que hablan español.

Comment: En catalán, del cual el valenciano es dialecto, sí distinguimos B de V. Bueno punto el hecho de que su influencia haga que sus hablantes trasladen esta diferenciación al castellano.

Comment: Ya en el latín vulgar de la península se perdió la diferencia fonética, como muestra que haya graffiti con faltas ortográficas (cosa que no ocurre en inglés, donde estos fonemas están claramente diferenciados)

Answer (score 1):

En México, y en mi experiencia con otros hispanoparlantes del continente americano, (Argentina, Chile, Estados Unidos, Guatemala, Nicaragua) si se hace una distinción al pronunciar el sonido de la "B" (labial) y "V" (labiodental).

La distinción tal vez pase desapercibida al oído del hispanoparlante que no la está buscando, pero para el extranjero es bastante notorio.

Tal vez sea evidencia meramente anecdótica pero solía compartir departamento con un amigo originario de Alemania y de inmediato relaciono la V labiodental con la V (Fau) teutona, que finalmente es el mismo sonido pero mucho más agresivo que en el español, y la B labial con su "Be" alemana que corresponden de manera análoga en los dos Idiomas.